# Computation timed out on GEE API (Python)

Tags: google-earth-engine, csv, point-in-polygon, google-earth-engine-python-api, geemap

I have a large set of points (with longitude and latitude) for which I need to extract the rasters (B1-B8A) in a CSV file. I am currently using [`geemap.extract_values_to_points`](https://geemap.org/geemap/#geemap.geemap.Map.extract_values_to_points).

```py
geemap.extract_values_to_points(
    points,
    composite_S2 ,
    './data/s2points-raster.csv',
    scale = ee.Projection('EPSG:3035').nominalScale())
```

This works for a smaller section but doing it on a larger set of points yields me the following error:

```
    HttpError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    File c:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\ee\data.py:328, in _execute_cloud_call(call, num_retries)
        327 try:
    --> 328   return call.execute(num_retries=num_retries)
        329 except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as e:
    
    File c:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py:130, in positional.<locals>.positional_decorator.<locals>.positional_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
        129         logger.warning(message)
    --> 130 return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    
    File c:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py:938, in HttpRequest.execute(self, http, num_retries)
        937 if resp.status >= 300:
    --> 938     raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
        939 return self.postproc(resp, content)
    
    HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/earthengine-legacy/value:compute?prettyPrint=false&alt=json returned "Computation timed out.". Details: "Computation timed out.">
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    EEException                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    location-of-notebook\extract-raster-points.ipynb Cell 9 in <module>
    ----> 1 geemap.extract_values_to_points(points, S2_of_countries_2018 ,'./data/s2points-raster.csv', scale = ee.Projection('EPSG:3035').nominalScale())
    
    File c:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\geemap\common.py:7776, in extract_values_to_points(in_fc, image, out_fc, scale, crs, crsTransform, tileScale, stats_type, timeout, proxies, **kwargs)
    ...
        328   return call.execute(num_retries=num_retries)
        329 except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as e:
    --> 330   raise _translate_cloud_exception(e)
    
    EEException: Computation timed out.
```

Looks like I'm running out of memory on gee? Because it works fine on smaller areas. Is there a way to overcome this in GEE? or an alternative way via which I could pull out raster point values from composite images of large polygons? Any piece of knowledge shared is highly appreciated.Thanks!

P.S.: This is the API version (on Python) and not the online CLI version on GEE (that uses javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `geemap.extract_values_to_points` function, but it looks like it is using Earth Engine's [interactive request environment](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/processing_environments#interactive-environment) for processing. In this case, requests must complete in 5 minutes. My guess is that it is taking more than five minutes to assemble the FeatureCollection for download as CSV. You have a few of options (among others). Also, if you are doing any processing to the images, consult the [best practices guide](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices) to ensure that your methods are efficient.

1. Break up your point collection into a few chunks and make multiple calls to `extract_values_to_points` in a for loop - concatenate the results later.
2. Export the CVS to Google Drive or Cloud Storage using `ee.Batch.Export` functions, which uses the [batch processing environment](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/processing_environments#batch-environment).
3. Try out the [high-volume request endpoint](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/processing_environments#high-volume-endpoint) to download point data in parallel - see [this blog post](https://gorelick.medium.com/fast-er-downloads-a2abd512aa26) for ideas.

Comment: Is there a way to split a FeatureCollection (FC) such that my FC with 8000 points can be split into 4000+4000 that way I can iteratively export and merge. I've been looking for a while but can't understand how to go about it. (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs)

Comment: I used the first approach and it worked as I broke down to 1000 points per Feature Collection using ee.FeatureCollection(points.toList(size, offset)). Thank you!